# Reduce whole text to some words in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem. I need a "text reducer".

What i mean: I wrote to text area any words, for example: John Doe is good boy; Then i press some button, and it will get something like:

John Doe

So, it will only output defined worlds, like John Doe, or milk or something like that

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please help me understand. Why would you want to do this? Why not just write the defined words to the textarea?

Comment: I want do a Hijackthis online analyzer, because our was closed

Comment: use substring function for reduce your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a black list of words you want to strip out, you could use the array replace function: `str_replace`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

like this:

```
$blacklist = ['ugly', 'bad', 'censored'];
$yourString = str_replace($yourString, $blacklist, '');
```

This will remove every word in your blacklist, from your input string.

If you need a whitelist based filter, you could use split your string into an array of words, and then use the `array_filter` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

using something similar to:

```
$whitelist = ['good', 'neat', 'stuff'];
$tokens = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $yourString);
$filtered = array_filter($tokens, function ($item) {
    return in_array($token, $whitelist);
});
$finalString = implode(' ', $filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write a function in this case it receives an array as parameter, but if is static, you could save it on the function.

Also, this could work using a regex with preg_match, but i'll leave that for you.

Currently ignores case thanks to `strtolower', if you don't want to ignore the case, remove this function calls.

```php
function printWhiteListedText($arrWhitelist, $str){

    $auxStr = "";

    foreach($arrWhitelist as $word){
        if(strpos(strtolower($str), strtolower($word)) > -1){
            $auxStr .= $word . ' ';
        }
    }

   return trim($auxStr);

}

echo printWhiteListedText(['Hello', 'world'], 'hello this world is great');
```